# jQuery code works for last iteration of php loop generated button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating a forum where people can vote on posts. The vote is called 'consents'.

```
<?php
$postshow = "SELECT * FROM ideas_1 ORDER BY consents DESC LIMIT 10";
$done = mysqli_query($conn, $postshow);
//$show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($done);

while ($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($done)) {
    echo"<div class = 'comments'>";
    echo"<br>";   
    echo"<br>";
    echo $show['post'];
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<p class = 'counter'>";
    echo $show['consents'];
    echo"</p>";
    echo"<br>";
    $postid = $show['postid'];
    $userid = $show['userid'];
    $consents = $show['consents'];
      $asd = "SELECT * FROM consents WHERE dept = 'ideas' and task = '1' and postid = '$postid' and voterid = '$id'";
      $doit = mysqli_query($conn, $asd);
      $exist = mysqli_num_rows($doit);
      if ($exist == 0){
    echo"<button id = \"consents$postid\">Consent This</button>";
      }
    echo"</div>";


}
?>
<script>
    var posterid = "<?php echo $userid;?>"
    var postid = "<?php echo $postid;?>"
    var voterid = "<?php echo $id;?>"
    var consents = "<?php echo $consents;?>"

$(document).ready(function () {   
   $('#consents' + postid).click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $.post ("consentsideas.php", {
        dept: "ideas",
        task: "1",
        postid: postid,
        voterid: voterid,
        consents: consents,
        posterid: posterid
    });
    $(".counter").html(++consents);
   });
   $(".answer").mousedown(function(){
            $(".post_answer").show();
            });
   $(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.post_answer').length) {
        if($('.post_answer').is(":visible")) {
            $('.post_answer').hide();
        }
    }        
}); 
  $(".post_answer").click(function(){
    var answer = $(".answer").val();
    $.post ("answerideas.php", {
        answer: answer,
        id: voterid
            });
    $(".answer").val('');
    });
}
  ); 
</script>
```

But any button looped by the while loop, when clicked, only updates the CONSENTS counter for the last iteration of the while loop. 
As you can see, I've made the button's id unique(I hope I did that correctly). So could anyone tell me where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your PHP; it's in your JavaScript. You're setting `postid` once, using the very last `$postid` that is set in the last iteration of the `while` loop.

One way to solve this problem is by binding the click event not to the id (like `#consents123`) but rather to a class that is set on each of the "Consent This" buttons (like `.consents`).

Then you'll need to cache the other data you need (like `postid`) somewhere, for example as a data attribute on the button, or in the element id, and then retrieve it when you need it in the click handler.

**PHP**

```
<button id = \"consents$postid\" class="consents" data-postid="$postid">Consent This</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('.consents').click(function() {
    ...
    var postid = $(this).data('postid');
    ...
});
```

Comment: So how do I fix that? Should I assign the JS variables inside the php loop?

Comment: @classifyed98 I added more to my post, let me know if you have more questions

Comment: and also the problem is that i would need all the other js variables too to be retrieved

Comment: @classifyed98 Sorry, mine was just a brief explanation. You'd need to cache all of the variables that you'll need to be unique for each button.

Comment: But won't the solution you've given also assign the last $postid to JS?

Comment: @classifyed98 You'll need to remove that `var postid` setting from the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

@musicnothing
Hey, I've edited my code a bit. Now it works. Thanks man!

```
while ($show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($done)) {
    $postid = $show['postid'];
    $userid = $show['userid'];
    $consents = $show['consents'];?>
   <div class = 'comments'>
    <?php echo$show['post'];?><br>
    <?php echo$show['consents'];?> <span>Consents</span>

     <?php $asd = "SELECT * FROM consents WHERE dept = 'ideas' and task = '1' and postid = '$postid' and voterid = '$id'";
      $doit = mysqli_query($conn, $asd);
      $exist = mysqli_num_rows($doit);
      if ($exist == 0){ ?>
    <button class = 'consents' data-postid = '<?php echo$postid;?>' data-posterid ='<?php echo$userid;?>'
    data-voterid = '<?php echo$id;?>' data-consents = '<?php echo$consents;?>' >Consent This</button>
     <?php } ?>
   </div>


<?php }
?>
<script>


    var voterid = "<?php echo $id;?>"


$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.consents').click(function(){
    var postid = $(this).data('postid');
    var consents = $(this).data('consents');
    var posterid = $(this).data('posterid');
    $(this).hide();
    $.post ("consentsideas.php", {
        dept: "ideas",
        task: "1",
        postid: postid,
        voterid: voterid,
        consents: consents,
        posterid: posterid
    });
    $(".counter").html(++consents);
   });
   $(".answer").mousedown(function(){
            $(".post_answer").show();
            });
   $(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.post_answer').length) {
        if($('.post_answer').is(":visible")) {
            $('.post_answer').hide();
        }
    }        
}); 
  $(".post_answer").click(function(){
    var answer = $(".answer").val();
    $.post ("answerideas.php", {
        answer: answer,
        id: voterid
            });
    $(".answer").val('');
    });
}
  ); 
</script>
```

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"<button class = 'consents' data-postid = '$postid' data-posterid ='$userid' data-voterid = '$id' data-consents = '$consents' >Consent This</button>";
      }



}
?>
<script>


$(document).ready(function () {


   $('.consents').click(function(){
    var posterid = $(this).data('posterid');
   var postid = $(this).data('postid');
   var voterid = $(this).data('voterid');
  var consents = $(this).data('consents');


    $(this).hide();
    $.post ("consentsideas.php", {
        dept: "ideas",
        task: "1",
        postid: postid,
        voterid: voterid,
        consents: consents,
        posterid: posterid
    });
    $(".counter").html(++consents);
   });
   $(".answer").mousedown(function(){
            $(".post_answer").show();
            });
   $(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.post_answer').length) {
        if($('.post_answer').is(":visible")) {
            $('.post_answer').hide();
        }
    }        
}); 
  $(".post_answer").click(function(){
    var answer = $(".answer").val();
    $.post ("answerideas.php", {
        answer: answer,
        id: voterid
            });
    $(".answer").val('');
    });
}
  ); 
</script>
```

Now the consent button won't work. And also, I'm not seeing my 'post' button(`$(".post_answer")`)